# Keep accordion style menu open on Lemonstand CMS system

Tags: jquery, menu

So I'm utilizing an accordion style menu (I suppose that's the proper terminology). The unique difficulty here I believe is that I'm using Lemonstand's integrated CMS system, which is a blessing and a nightmare all in one. I'm not sure how many people will be familiar with lemonstand's API and all, but I figured I'd post here to look for help first.

What I'm looking to do is keep the "dropdown" open after clicking. The JS used is found below:

```
 <script>
function initMenu() {
  $('#menu ul').hide(); // Hide the submenu
  if ($('#menu li').has('ul')) $('#menu ul').prev().addClass('expandable'); // Expand/collapse a submenu when it exists  
  $('.expandable').click(function(e) { // Prevent Default
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
        $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
      }
    );
  }

// When document ready, call initMenu() function 
$(document).ready(function() {initMenu();}); </script>
```

I'm certain this is fairly easy, but as far as js goes I'm quite new to the whole thing.

```
<? $category_listing = isset($parent) ? $parent->list_children('front_end_sort_order') : Shop_Category::create()->list_root_children('front_end_sort_order'); ?>
<? if ($category_listing->count()): ?>
<? if (!isset($parent)): ?>

<nav>
<ul id="menu">
<? else: ?>
<ul>
<? endif ?>

<? foreach ($category_listing as $_category): ?>

<li<?= (isset($category) && $category->id == $_category->id) ? ' class="current"' : '' ?>>
<a href="<?= $_category->page_url('bifrost-sandbox/category') ?>"><?= h($_category->name) ?></a>
<? $this->render_partial('sandbox:temp', array('parent' => $_category)) ?>
</li>
<? endforeach ?>
</ul>
<? if (!isset($parent)): ?>
<nav>

<? endif ?>
<? endif ?>
```

If anyone can help me out, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Replace $(this).toggleClass('expanded'); with $(this).addClass('expanded');

Comment: @defau1t Thanks for your comment, but this still doesn't change anything. It actually doesn't seem to effect it at all :-)

Comment: If you post your markup that would be useful and help us to understand how the DOM is structured.

Comment: added, let me know if theres anything else i can do to help with this, my apologizes for the oversight @defau1t

Comment: did you try removing this $(this).next().slideToggle();

Comment: That causes the menu system to malfunction. Everything appears correct until you click on one of the dropdowns, then the css works fine, but the menu doesn't drop down. (CSS works fine meaning the arrow turns around.